# How to add button to UIDocumentInteractionController preview

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uidocumentinteraction, uidocument

I'm using `UIDocumentInteractionController` for files preview:

```
interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(url);    
interactionController.Delegate = new UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegateClass(this);    
InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{interactionController.PresentPreview(true);}
});
```

How can I add a custom button on the top of the view to perform some action?